# How do I modify the 'render' to see the rates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to render the exchange rates from a server to my page.
Here is my React code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            exRates: []
        };
    }
    getCurrencyRatesFromDB = () => {
        fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest')
           .then((response) => {
             console.log('then 1', response);
            return response.json();                                                                     
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log('then 2', data);
            this.setState({
                exRates: data.rates
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log('render started');
        return (
            <div>
                console.log('return started'),
                <button 
                    type="button" 
                    className="btn"
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.getCurrencyRatesFromDB();                                          
                    }}
                    >
                        Load rates
                </button>
                <p>{this.state}</p>
        </div>        
        )
    }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

How do I modify the 'render' part to see the rates in a column like it is on the server?

Answer (score 0):

In your render method, `map` the rates from state as:

```
render() {
        console.log('render started');
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.exRates.map(rate => {
                   return <div>{rate.toString()}</div>
                 })}
                <button 
                    type="button" 
                    className="btn"
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.getCurrencyRatesFromDB();                                          
                    }}
                    >
                        Load rates
                </button>
                <p>{this.state}</p>
        </div>        
        )
    }
```

Comment: Now it is giving me the error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {exRates}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at src/index.js:42)
    in div (at src/index.js:28)
    in App (at src/index.js:48)

Comment: Update your question with the JSON you are getting from API.

Comment: I did not exactly understand what you meant, but here is the JSON:
https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest

Comment: This should work. Try the answer once again. You need to map you cann't display then directly.

Comment: No arguments. But I'm still getting this error. Can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Muhammad's answer, you need to iterate through an `Object`, not an `Array`, and you can't `map` through an Object. You'll have to use `Object.keys` for that.

```
  {exRates
    ? Object.keys(exRates).map((elem, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            <span key={i}>
              {[elem]} :{exRates[elem]}
            </span>
            <br />
          </>
        );
      })
    : null}
```

Inside the `Object.keys(exRates)`, `elem` is the name of the key and `exRates[elem]` is the key's value.

Comment: Had to add 'this' to 'exRates' otherwise it said it was not defined. After that it all ended up with the same mistake.
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {exRates}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Because you have to remove {this.state} inside ```p``` tags. 

Take a look at this https://pastebin.com/19gt1dPh . This should be your entire ```render()``` method

Comment: @Mikhail so did it help?